# Undo or reset the faked migrations in django

Tags: python, django, django-models

In my project which is based on django-1.8.2 I was facing some problems with migrations so i ran command

```
python manage.py migrate --fake
```

But it faked all the migrations which this command is meant for. But now `python manage.py migrate` command is not doing or applying any migration. I want to undo the faked migrations so that I can apply the migrations to database. I want to apply the existing migrations to the database.

Answer (score 28):

For each app, you can fake the migrations back to where they were before you faked them.

```
python manage.py migrate --fake myapp 00XX_last_migration
```

where `00XX_last_migration` is the last migration that you actually ran for your app `myapp`.

Or, if you haven't actually run any migrations for that app yet:

```
python manage.py migrate --fake myapp zero
```

Comment: If you want to see all your migrations for all your apps, you can run `python manage.py showmigrations`. From there you can determine which migration you would like to roll back to.

Comment: Worked perfectly in September 2020, Django v.3.0.8

Comment: I think it is worth mentioning that if the faked migration was on number say `0018` then you'd want to run the above command with the last REAL migration aka eg `0017`

Comment: @jfunk careful, that suggests to me that you subtract one from `0018` to get `0017`. But it’s possible, for example, that you started on `0015`, and that `—fake` marked `0016`, `0017` and `0018` as applied. In that case you would fake back to `0015`.

Comment: Good call, I was just trying to clarify that you want to go back to the last REAL since I just ran into this and it wasn't immediately obvious.

Comment: This was gold worth! Gpt told me its not reversable, but this is they way to go!!! THANKS

Answer (score 10):

From [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-option---fake):

> be warned that using --fake runs the risk of putting the migration state table into a state where *manual recovery* will be needed to make migrations run correctly.

So I suggest you to simply remove faked migrations from `django_migrations` table.

Comment: The warning from the docs applies whether you use `--fake` or manually add/remove rows from the `django_migrations` table. Both approaches can lead to your database and `django_migrations` table getting out of sync, which can be tricky to resolve.