# Django: how to completely skip a migration?

Tags: python, django, django-migrations

I want to be able to not run a `Django 1.8` migration.

I have seen people use the `--fake` option, but it's not a valid alternative for me, since it writes a new record on the django migrations database table. I dont like this, because I want to be able to run that migration on a later moment, and that wouldn't happen since django thinks it has been already done.

Is there any other way of avoiding to run a migration?

Comment: Probably not, since the later migrations depend on the ones before.

Comment: how about *not* doing ./manage.py migrate ?

Comment: @e4c5 in that case I would not be running some migrations which the app really does need.

Comment: then as @RemcoGerlich points out, you can't do this because migrations are likely to depend on earlier ones.

Comment: You can [undo the faked migrations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31731211/undo-or-reset-the-faked-migrations-in-django/31731507#31731507) later, then run them for real. You can then fake any migrations that you have already run. Running migrations in the wrong order like this might cause problems.

Comment: You can delete the migration file and generate it again when required? You would need to amend the migration that has the deleted migration as a dependency